# Bluetooth Can't Find Android Phone

Tags: bluetooth, broadcom

I am dual booting Ubuntu 17.04 and Windows 10. Bluetooth on Windows finds my android phone but Ubuntu doesn't.

There was an error in `dmesg` about a missing file (more output at the bottom of the question)

```
[   11.127095] Bluetooth: hci0: HP-745-G2
[   11.130089] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[   11.135450] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21fb.hcd failed with error -2
[   11.135457] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21fb.hcd not found
```

I downloaded a copy from [here](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21fb.hcd) and put it in `/lib/firmware/brcm/` as root then did a full shutdown and start up.

This time there was no error in `dmesg` but blueman lists no adapters available.

```
    [   10.805497] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
    [   10.822505] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
    [   10.824508] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
    [   11.839514] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [   11.839516] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [   11.839522] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [   12.057529] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 1766
    [   12.074516] Bluetooth: hci0: DW1550 Bluetooth 4.0 LE
```

I also tried booting in to Windows and found the driver at `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\BCM20702A1_001.002.014.1502.1766.hex`

I then used [hex2hcd](https://github.com/jessesung/hex2hcd) to convert it and replaced the other hcd file and shutdown/started. However, it made no difference.

i.e. there was no error in `dmesg` but no adapters are available.

When there was an error, there seemed to be adapters! I am confused.

Diagnostics below:

`uname -a`

```
Linux HP-745-G2 4.10.14-041014-generic #201705031501 SMP Wed May 3 19:03:05 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lsb_release -d`

```
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
```

`rfkill list all`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

`lspci -nnk|grep -iA2 net; lsusb; hciconfig -a; dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0e)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:221c]
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
        Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
        DeviceName: WLAN
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [103c:2154]
        Kernel driver in use: wl
        Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0374 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21fb Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
        BD Address: 28:C2:DD:E5:A6:F9  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1                                                                                                                                                            
        UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        RX bytes:1582 acl:0 sco:0 events:87 errors:0                                                                                                                                                                             
        TX bytes:3571 acl:0 sco:0 commands:87 errors:0                                                                                                                                                                           
        Features: 0xbf 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87                                                                                                                                                                        
        Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3                                                                                                                                                                         
        Link policy: RSWITCH SNIFF                                                                                                                                                                                               
        Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        Name: 'HP-745-G2'                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        Class: 0x0c010c                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing                                                                                                                                                                                    
        Device Class: Computer, Laptop                                                                                                                                                                                           
        HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x1000                                                                                                                                                                                 
        LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x220e                                                                                                                                                                               
        Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)                                                                                                                                                                                  

[    0.023227] [Firmware Info]: CPU: Re-enabling disabled Topology Extensions Support.
[    0.775103] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    3.692630] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 1.64 Family ID: 9
[    3.695971] [drm] Found VCE firmware/feedback version 40.2.2 / 15!
[   11.004113] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   11.004148] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   11.004153] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   11.004157] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   11.004165] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.110092] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[   11.127095] Bluetooth: hci0: HP-745-G2
[   11.130089] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[   11.135450] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21fb.hcd failed with error -2
[   11.135457] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21fb.hcd not found
[   16.920082] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   16.920084] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   16.920090] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   31.547710] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   31.547725] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   31.547734] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: The `brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21fb.hcd` is still not found. This means that the name or path of the file is wrong. Please [edit] your question and add output of `ls /lib/firmware/brcm` command.